# Как поменять местами значение двух переменных

Tags: java, логика

Имеются

```
String a = "first_string";
String b = "second_string";
```

и кнопка по нажатию которой должны меняться местами значения двух переменных.
Сделал так:

```
if (!click){
    b = first_string;
    a = second_string;
    click = true;
} else {
    b = first_string;
    a = second_string;
    click = false;
}
```

Но мне кажется код слишком громоздкий.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли краткое решение этой задачи?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к Android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно сделать короче:

```
String c = a;
a = b;
b = c;
click = !click.
```

Comment: А без булевы возможно сделать?

Comment: @TITAN, это знаете только вы, т. к. только вы видели свой код. Никто не знает, используется ли `click` еще где-то.

Comment: Нет, если по нажатию только одной кнопки...

Comment: @TITAN, будте добры, перестаньте говорить загадками, если хотите, чтобы кто-то вам помог. Если нигде больше не используете - можете удалить. Вы, в конце концов, сами можете проверить просто запустив приложение.

Comment: Извините, но я... Ну ладно!!! Спасибо!)